# Story about alien race which evolved from plants instead of animals

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall when I was young (about 30+ years ago) I saw on TV a movie about a humanoid alien race which evolved from plants instead of animals. I was about 6 or 8 so I don't remember much about it, but it might have been in black and white (though not completely sure).

It had some horror tone to it, since aliens could destroy humans or something, though I don't know if it's possible to call it a "horror movie". And if I recall correctly they planted eggs or something similar to eggs to reproduce. The alien race might have been from Mars, thought not completely sure.

Does anyone have an idea which movie it could be?

Comment: May have been "The Thing from Another World", sometimes referred to as "The Thing", a 1951 American black-and-white science fiction-horror based on the novella "Who Goes There?" by John W. Campbell?

Comment: @jim I think I've seen that movie, isnt a movie set in the Antartica? if it's that one, it isnt

Comment: OK, this can be scratched from the possibilities

Comment: @Pablo - Just to double-check... there is a 1980s John Carpenter color movie called "The Thing" based more faithfully on the same short story, but the 1951 black-and-white version jim mentions definitely features humanoid creatures discussed as having evolved from plants, and the movie would probably not be scary to a 6- to 8-year-old. Were you possibly referring to the Carpenter version in your comment above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am Groot.

I remember a movie from 1966 called [Queen of Blood](http://www.aycyas.com/liz_qob.htm).  It has green skinned aliens on Mars.  One is female.  One of the humans thinks she may be descended from plants.  She kills for blood.  At the end you find that she's laid eggs.  Could this be what you're trying to recall?

Comment: Well done! It was a hard find

Comment: wow, that sounds cool for a 1960s movie plot. but maybe in fairness sometimes early science fiction had decent ideas but poor specials effects (and often bad dialog and acting. Quite a cast -- besides Hopper and Rathbone, one actress was in 1953 War of the Worlds.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind is the really terrible, from the point of view of a fan of the book, movie rendition of *Day of the Triffids* from '62 or '63. The film was released in both colour and black and white; you could have seen it in black and white but it would be a bit odd. I have seen the thing but can't remember much about it except that the Triffids were portrayed more as aliens than engineered plants, which is what makes me think it might be the film you're looking for.

Comment: Do the aliens look like plants or like humanoids? The one I'm talking about they were a humanoid race which evolved from plants

Comment: @Pablo Ah yeah, no they don't, you might want to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Since you were very young and feel it has a horror feel to it. It reminded me of [*Invasion Of The Body Snatchers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers_(1978_film)) from 1978.

Plants on Earth are "infected" by an alien species. The plants then take over humans and control them, effectively taking over the world.

Looking into it further, the 1978 version is not the original film. The original is from 1956 and in black and white, also called [*Invasion of the Body Snatchers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers).

Comment: hmm I would have to see it, but it doesnt sound like it. These were aliens who evolved from plants through thousands of years of evolution (just like humans evolved from primates), not plants who were infected by aliens. They dont metamorph during the movie, it's just mentioned they evolved from plants

Comment: OK.. then I really gotta dig deep to find it, or I simply might not know ;)